# Boto3 - change_resource_record_sets change record type fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-3.6, amazon-route53

I'm trying to update the type of an existing record using `boto3.change_resource_record_sets` in my current case, I'm trying to change a record from type A to type CNAME - with matching values.

I'm getting the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidChangeBatch:
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets
operation: RRSet of type A with DNS name test.test.v3.prod.example.com.
is not permitted because a conflicting RRSet of type  CNAME with the same
DNS name already exists in zone test.v3.prod.example.com.
```

This operation exactly can be accomplished via AWS UI (Only an update of a record in the same zone I'm trying to update from my code).

This is my code:

```
def update_record(zone_id):
  batch = {
    'Changes': [
      {
        'Action': 'UPSERT',
        'ResourceRecordSet' : {
          'Name' : 'test.test.v3.prod.example.com.',
          'Type' : 'CNAME',
          'TTL' : 15,
          'ResourceRecords' : [{'Value': 'www.example.com'}]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  # THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION
  response = client.change_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId=zone_id, ChangeBatch=batch)

  return response
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the record **type** with UPSERT. The name and the type are used as a key for which ttl and resource records to change. Your Changes should be:

```
batch = {
  'Changes': [
    {
      'Action': 'DELETE',
      'ResourceRecordSet' : {
        'Name' : 'test.test.v3.prod.example.com.',
        'Type' : 'A',                                # or AAAA
        'TTL' : 15,
        'ResourceRecords' : [{'Value': '1.2.3.4'}]   # or whatever it is
      }
    },
    {
      'Action': 'UPSERT',                            # INSERT, really!
      'ResourceRecordSet' : {
        'Name' : 'test.test.v3.prod.example.com.',
        'Type' : 'CNAME',
        'TTL' : 15,
        'ResourceRecords' : [{'Value': 'www.example.com'}]
      }
    ]
  }
```